# How to fix Failed to connect to host for https://cocoapods.org in flutter?

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, flutter-doctor

When I run 'flutter doctor -v' Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.5, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64) , I get this check:

```
[!] HTTP Host Availability

    ✗ HTTP host "https://cocoapods.org/" is not reachable. Reason: Failed to connect to host in 10 seconds.`
```

I tried to re-install cocoapods but it didn't work.

Comment: For me manually going to https://cocoapods.org/ for testing if it works and then running the `flutter doctor` command after page loaded worked. I think it may be because https://cocoapods.org/ takes longer than 10 seconds sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrade and changing the channel, it helped me.

```
flutter upgrade
flutter channel master
flutter doctor -v
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it might happen. What you can do is, like the previous answer, do an upgrade of your flutter (or maybe not). Nonetheless, you can:

```bash
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

This can solve your problem in most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating Microsoft defender. After Disabling Defender, the problem went away. **Real-time protection** and **cloud-based protection** turn it off via the Defender app. Check again with **flutter doctor** command.

After it was fixed, I activate the antivirus and the problem did not appear again.

In addition, sometimes such an error occurs due to poor internet connection.